# Is there a power function in CSS?

Tags: css, css-calc

I know you can write a power function in Sass with a loop. Is there one specifially in CSS? Or a way to write one?

Comment: no, sass just pre-compile your SCSS code to normal CSS code...

Comment: what should be the use case?

Comment: yes there is: https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2331 but you need to wait for their support, probably another year

Comment: the draft spec: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#exponent-funcs

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan For me, calculating a responsive type scale. In Temani's first link there is a discussion with more use cases.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks. If you want to post these links as an answer, I would except it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [working group already approved such functions](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2331#issuecomment-467990627)

> The CSS Working Group just discussed trig, and agreed to the following:

> RESOLVED: Add sin() cos() tan() acos() asin() atan() atan2() hypot() sqrt() pow()

And it's now under the [CSS Values and Units Module Level 4 Specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#exponent-funcs):

> The exponential functions `pow()`, `sqrt()`, `hypot()`, `log()`, and `exp()`
> compute various exponential functions with their arguments.

> The `pow(A, B)` function contains two comma-separated calculations A and B, both of which must resolve to `<number>`s, and returns the result of raising A to the power of B, returning the value as a `<number>`.

We only need to wait for [their support by the browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pow#browser_compatibility)